# Pass a path argument having brackets to a MS DOS Batch file

Tags: robotframework

I need to achieve the below using Robotframework script:

```
c:\>runbatch "C:\Program Files (x86)\tool\bin\test.exe"      C:\tool\get.ini
```

where **runbatch** is a MS DOS Batch and **"C:\Program Files (x86)\tool\bin\test.exe"** and **C:\tool\get.ini** are parameters to the batch file. The first argument contains path of a tool that has **"(" and ")"** in its path.

So in my Robot script I have a variable like below:

```
${tool_path}        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\tool\\bin\\test.exe"
${tool_ini}        "C:\tool"
```

And invoke like below:

```
${RC}=    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/../scripts/runbatch.bat    ${tool_path}    ${tool_ini}\\get.ini
```

The execution fails but note when I run it via the same param thru the command line as standalone batch it works fine.

In the batch I added comments to just log the arguments and I found that they are completely distorted, the tool_path value is completely distorted **("\"C:\Program**) and second argument becomes (**Files** ) - how can I fix the issue in robot script such that when a path is passed having braces are not modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also escape the backslashes in `${tool_ini}` - make its value `c:\\tool`; that's not the culprit thought, just something else to change.

Remove the double quotes in the arguments' values - `Run Process` does not need them in the way you are calling it, with a keyword argument per script argument. E.g.:

```
${tool_path}        C:\\Program Files (x86)\\tool\\bin\\test.exe
${tool_ini}            C:\\tool

${RC}=    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/../scripts/runbatch.bat    ${tool_path}    ${tool_ini}\\get.ini
```

The way you've put them, they have become a part of the value itself.

---

Alternatively, keeping the double quotes there, you can call the script with all arguments in the call line:

```
${tool_path}        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\tool\\bin\\test.exe"
${tool_ini}         C:\\tool

${RC}=    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/../scripts/runbatch.bat ${tool_path} "${tool_ini}\\get.ini"
```

*(the second one doesn't really need quotes, but I've added them for consistency)*

---

By the way, not really an issue, yet - the script path uses slashes (**/**), which is a bit unorthodox for Windows. Contrary to the popular believe, the OS does support this path delimiter pretty much the same way as it supports backslashes (**\**), it's just not widely used and looks a bit out of place.

Comment: Yes the missing double '\' in c:\tool was a type issue in my question .Thanks it worked - alternatively when I used ${cmdfile}=    Remove String    ${tool_path}    " and made use of ${cmdfile} instead of   ${tool_path} it also worked - thanks a lot for your help